# Cascading html.DropDownListFor in .net core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, html.dropdownlistfor

I am at the point where I am loosing my mind. So to avoid that, I have to ask you this questions.
Now, I know, that there are lot of "similar" questions out there. Believe me, I have spend the last 3 days looking at them, but none of them is working for me. So I hope you will be able to help me with this.

I have been following a course on Udemy.com about ASP.NET Core and Razor Pages. With some changes I have managed to create my little own project. However I am missing only one thing at the moment.

I would like to have a DropDownListFor with selections based on what is selected in another DropDownListFor.

In short I have to db tables. One called Team and one called RepairType. Each repairtype is done by one of the teams.

So my Model looks like this:

```
public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Repair Team")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
} 

public class RepairType
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Repair Type")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Repair Team")]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a VievModel:

```
public class RepairVM
{
    public Repair Repair { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RepairTypeList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TeamList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DeckList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserList { get; set; }

}
```

I have a few repositories that look like this:

```
public class TeamRepository : Repository<Team>, ITeamRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public TeamRepository(ApplicationDbContext db) : base(db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetTeamListForDropDown()
    {
        return _db.Team.Select(i => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = i.Name,
            Value = i.Id.ToString()
        });
    }

 public class RepairTypeRepository : Repository<RepairType>, IRepairTypeRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public RepairTypeRepository(ApplicationDbContext db) : base(db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetRepairTypeListForDropDown()
    {
        return _db.RepairType.Select(i => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = i.Name,
            Value = i.Id.ToString()
        });
    }
```

In my Razor Page, I have these two html.DropDownListFor:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <label asp-for="RepairObj.Repair.TeamId"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RepairObj.Repair.TeamId, Model.RepairObj.TeamList, "- Please select a Team -", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "javascript:GetType(this.value);" })
                    <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="RepairObj.Repair.TeamId"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <label asp-for="RepairObj.Repair.RepairTypeId"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RepairObj.Repair.RepairTypeId, Model.RepairObj.RepairTypeList, "- Please select a Repair Type -", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="RepairObj.Repair.RepairTypeId"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And my code when loading the page looks like this:

```
public class CreateRepairModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitofWork;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    


    public CreateRepairModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _unitofWork = unitOfWork;
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
       
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public RepairVM RepairObj { get; set; }

    
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        
        RepairObj = new RepairVM
        {                
            TeamList = _unitofWork.Team.GetTeamListForDropDown(),
            RepairTypeList = _unitofWork.RepairType.GetRepairTypeListForDropDown(),
            DeckList = _unitofWork.Deck.GetDeckListForDropDown(),
            Repair = new Models.Repair()
        };
        
        return Page();
    }
```

I have tried javaScript, jQuery and so on, but as I said, nothing really works for me. Please have in mind that this is my first ever web application project, so I am really hoping that someone will be so kind, and tell me exactly what to do, so that I will only have the repairtype in the dropdownlist that match the teams dropdownlist.

I hope it all makes sense and I will be happy to supply you with more information if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: What my approach here would be to have an `onclick` (to js functions) on the dropdowns which you want to cascade from. In the js functions use ajax calls to get the data to fill the cascading dropdowns. Crete markup and populate the cascading dropdowns with that markup. That way every time you change the parent, the child contains the correct data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use data-attribute for the option fields so we could filter, hence the repair list has to be manually filled. Follow the steps below;

1. Add the class `team-select` to Teams dropdown. We will use this to bind our event later.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RepairObj.Repair.TeamId, Model.RepairObj.TeamList, "- Please select a Team -", new { @class = "form-control team-select"})
```

2. Use this as your Repair dropdown. In each option, I used data-attribute; `data-team`.

```
/* 
We have to manually fill the options because SelectListItem doesn't support data-attribute.
I also added the class repair-select for event bind.
*/

<select name="RepairObj.Repair.RepairTypeId" class="repair-select form-control">
   <option>- Please select a Repair Type -</option>
   @foreach(var type in Model.RepairObj.RepairTypeList){
      <option data-team="@type.TeamId" value="@type.Id">@type.Name</option>
   }
</select>
```

3. Then use this script.

```
@section scripts {
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

         // bind an event everytime team select is changed
         $(".team-select").change(function(){

            // get the selected teamId
            var teamId = $(this).val();

            // loop through all option
            $(".repair-select option").each(function(){

               // get the team id from data-attribute; data-team
               var dataTeamId = $(this).data("team");

               // if the dataTeamId is equal to teamId, show it, else hide
               if(dataTeamId == teamId){
                  $(this).show();
                  $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
               }
               else{
                  $(this).hide();
                  $(this).attr("disabled",true);
               }
            });
            
            // select the first option in repairType dropdown
            $(".repair-select option").eq(0).prop("selected", true);
         });
      });
   </script>
}
```

4. Update `GetRepairTypeListForDropDown` to the code below.

```
public List<RepairType> GetRepairTypeListForDropDown()
{
   return _db.RepairType.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Hi Jerdine,
This look really promising and simple. I hope it works. But unfortunatly I get 3 errors in the option line inside the foreach loop. 
It says: "SelecListItem does not contain a definition for TeamId, Id and Name. 
Any idea why?

Comment: @MortenBalleHansen ah darn, my bad. I was assuming `Model.RepairObj.RepairTypeList` is a `List<RepairType>`, let me fix that 5mins

Comment: @MortenBalleHansen updated the answer. Changed your repository function to return `List<RepairType>`

Comment: you are a life saver. Or at least you saved me from going crazy. It's working and it is such a simple solution that even I understand. I can't thank you enough. :-) The only thing is, that when selecting a team, and then a repairtype, and if I then select another team, the repairtyp for the previous team is still there. Any change it can be cleared when selecting another team?

Comment: @MortenBalleHansen you're welcome! u wrote the question and code neatly too, hence i was able to understand.

Comment: @MortenBalleHansen I updated the script and added `$(".repair-select option").eq(0).prop("selected", true);` This will select the first option after hide/show